# new file on desktop makes wallpaper vanish

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, display-driver

I have a bit of a weird issue with my work PC, its a dell machine with an i7-7700 CPU so intel 630 graphics, I'm using the latest drivers from the dell website for the graphics which is 23.20.16.4973, I did try to install the latest from intels website but due to the changes in driver architecture from intel the installer says its not validated on this pc and won't install.

on to the issue:
if I right click on the desktop and select new > text file sometimes (say one time in 5) the wallpaper might vanish, but sometimes it goes from all monitors but sometimes only from one or two (I have a triple monitor setup, 1920x1080 center, with 1440x900 either side)

If the wallpaper had previously disappeared then the same actions may make it come back on one or more monitors.

I've looked through the event viewer and there isn't any events from explorer corresponding with when these events happen.

how on earth can I diagnose this?

Comment: Your work PC administrator may have some scripts that may be running in the background. There is a `BGInfo.exe` that may IT administrators use, to print computer names, ip address and other relevant IT info on your desktop wallpaper.

Comment: @Cricrazy BGInfo is being used on this pc, but its also being used across the whole domain and every PC (all brand new and imaged at same time) is configured them same, this issue hasn't presented on any other computers

Comment: The drivers you have installed are extremely outdated.  If the only GPU you have is the iGPU, then you should [update your drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28139/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=88355), but this issue might not be solved by the drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound as stated in the post, the drivers direct from Intel won't install and the drivers are already the latest offered by dell, how can I update when they won't install?

Comment: Are you not running at least 1803?  You can download the previous [driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28289/Legacy-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10) to that though.

Comment: First make sure to use the latest and correct graphics driver. If the problem persists, try using just one monitor or just two monitors or just three monitors. Compare the three cases to see if there is exactly the same problem. If there is no problem just using one monitor;  it occasionally has such a problem just  using two monitors; it often has such a problem just using three monitors, it may be that the graphics card cannot bear three monitors.